# Java Debugging Interface (com.sun.jdi) package missing in IntelliJ 2017.1-C

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, jdi

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1 to work on a project that involves using a Greenfoot port ([GitHub](http://github.com/houbie/greenfoot)) that's optimized to use Groovy. The code is perfectly fine, but IntelliJ is telling me that com.sun.jdi doesn't exist. I am unsure as to how I might fix this. Any ideas?

Sidenote: I don't know much about how JDI correlates with VM, which I suspect may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `tools.jar` to the JSDK **classpath** used for this project:

[image: tools.jar]

Comment: For me, this issue showed up as a `ClassNotFoundError` for `com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException`. Recording it here in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: Even it there but still IntelliJ is not able to detect.