# How do I get an instance of a class if one exists, else create it?

Tags: java

I am writing a command framework and people can register commands from any class with their own method. I am trying to invoke these methods when a user enters a command.

I want to make it possible for the developer to use their own constructor and create an instance of the command classes if they wish, but if not I will load it myself.

This is the code I have so far:

```
mapping.getMethod().invoke(mapping.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().newInstance(), paramValues);
```

The flaw with this method is it generates a new instance each time which is also going to error for classes that do not have a default blank constructor.

How am I able to grab an instance of a class which could be in runtime, and if not create one?

Comment: I think that you are looking for a lazy implementation of the singleton design pattern.   There are a few correct ways to implement that ... and some incorrect ways.

Comment: I agree, but I don't really want to force upon users of my API to follow this design. I would love for them to be able to initialise their own classes if they need to (i.e. provide data to the class through a constructor), and if not then I'll initialise.

Comment: Just an idea, check if the following class and method can help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/VirtualMachine.html#classesByName-java.lang.String-

Comment: @leogtzr - thanks for the suggestion. I don't seem to have the com.sun.jdi package. I am using JDK 8. I have done lots of research but nothing has been fruitful. The most promising thread I looked at was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024326/java-debugging-interface-com-sun-jdi-package-missing-in-intellij-2017-1-c/43026109#43026109 but I do not have the tools.jar in my JDk 8 (note: I know the screenshot shows 7, but I must compile in 8 - it should contain it still, no?).